# Linear subspace of K[X]?

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the following task from my professor and I wanted to ask for advice from you.

Task:

- $K$ is a field

I shall prove this statement

Prove that for every $v$ element of $K$ the set $I_v = \{f\,\text{element}\, K[X]/f(v) = 0\}$ is a linear subspace of $K[X]$!

---

I don't need to prove that much here just that: if p and q are polynoms, $p(v) = 0$ and $q(v) = 0$, $p + q$ is a polynom with $(p+q)(v) = 0$.

Same for the scalar multiplication.

Though I don't know how to write it down here.

---

If possible tell me if my thoughts are right and maybe complete my solutions if they are nearly right or give me useful hints?

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this set isn't empty!

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot it's one of three linear subspace axioms, but do you know how I can formulate it ? Since I don't really know how to.

Comment: What you wrote is correct just add the forgotten axiom:)

Comment: But that can't be the solution in my opinion, it's too freaking easy, I mean we have a whole week for this kind of task and then it's solved so easily ? But if you say so, I thank you alot. And I can even formulate it in such a plain way ? I'm kinda speechless right now. But thanks.

Comment: @Sai Well, then use the time to pep it up a bit. Interpret $I_v$ as the kernel of some suitable linear map.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using the [One-Step Vector Subspace Test](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). Explicitly, let $f,g\in I_v$ and let $\lambda\in K$. Then
$$
(f+\lambda\cdot g)(v)=f(v)+\lambda\cdot g(v)=\bf 0+\lambda\cdot\bf 0=\bf 0+\bf0=\bf0
$$
Hence $f+\lambda\cdot g\in I_v$ and $I_v$ is a subspace of $K[X]$ as required.

The result also follows from an observation of @k.stm. Let $T:K[X]\to K$ be the linear map $T(f)=f(v)$. Then $I_v=\ker T$ and, of course, the kernel of any linear map is a subspace of its domain.